# Kendo grid dynamic edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i'm using kendo ui for html5 web app. and i need to edit only one column (i.e., Unit) and when it is changed, the Amount column should update automatically. for example:

1 unit = $10,
if i change 1 unit to 5, then amount changes to $50.

How can i achieve this.

Previously I posted a part of my code. now i have done a telerik dojo example.
please take a look here

[Working Example with Source code](http://dojo.telerik.com/@varanjith/ePOrA/5)

**Update #1:**

The demo looks clumsy, i'm sorry for that. click the button with number in first page, then click the cart icon on the top right corner.

This image explains what i want to do with that cart page
[image: Kendo datasource grid doubt]
How can i do that?

Update #2:

Thanks to @RobertoDeLaParra
For his solution, i came closer completing. but i have a new issue.

[image]

When i change the Unit, the aggregate and the Amount field in edit box, doesn't change.

Please take a look at this dojo,

http://dojo.telerik.com/@varanjith/ePOrA/5

Thank you.

Comment: You need to bind a model to your schema and make only the unit property in your model editable

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra Thanks for the response my friend. but i use two datasource, 1. Product & 2.Cart. The one i select in Product, is inserted into the cart datasource. So in this case, how can i bind the schema?

I kept the schema model empty.

Comment: Could you share a working jsFiddler? I'll take a look into it.

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra I've added a working demo, here at this link http://dojo.telerik.com/@varanjith/ePOrA/5 ..
Please look at my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi change your amount field for this:

```
   {
    field: "Amount",
    title: "Amount",                  
    footerTemplate: "<div class='ra'>#= sum # </div>",
    template: "<div class='ra'>#= Amount * Unit # </div>"
   }
```

and after initializing the cartGrid add this:

```
var cartGrid = $("#CartGrid").data("kendoGrid");
cartGrid.bind("edit", function (e){
            //console.log(e.model);
            var unitPrice = e.model.UnitPrice;
            var unit = e.model.Unit;
            //This code replace the input generated by kendo with our custom HTML 

            $("td[data-container-for='Amount']").html(unitPrice*unit);
});
```

Comment: Hi Roberto, please take a look on my updated question. and Thanks again.